# Bean definition options

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

Just a quick question related to defining beans in Spring and Java EE.
In Spring I can define beans using annotations, xml and through configuration classes.

So far the only option in Java EE I've found is to use annotations. Are there other ways of defining beans in Java EE that I'm not aware of?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nope, AFAIK. Pretty much that or the xml config files that the annotations were born to supplant

Comment: Thanks kolossus, thats all I wanted to know.